# Override ParallelWebappClassLoader for one webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I need to set a custom wrapped classloader as ParallelWebappClassLoader for a one webapp only. Do I have a way to do that?

Also anyone have a idea how is the ParallelWebappClassLoader set as default class loader in a webapp in tomcat. When I add a debug point to loadClass(String) method it hits to loadClass method of ParallelWebappClassLoader. How can I change that to my custom class loader and the look in ParallelWebappClassLoader if I need?

Thanks

#tomcat #java #classloader #ParallelWebappClassLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom class loader via a `Loader` element nested in the `Context` element for your application.

For example, add the following in the file `META-INF/context.xml` packaged in the WAR file:

```
<Context>
  <Loader loaderClass="fully.quialified.package.name.of.your.ClassLoader" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Thanks you Mark, I could sort my problem using java.system.class.loader system property. I added My own class loader and I could serve class definitions from another war's class loader